# How to import .AVI files?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to import an .avi file for frame processing.

```
Import["c:\\windows\\clock.avi","Elements"]
Import["c:\\windows\\clock.avi","VideoEncoding"]
Import["c:\\windows\\clock.avi"]
Import["c:\\windows\\clock.avi",{"Frames",{5,6}}]

Out[115]= {Animation,BitDepth,ColorSpace,Data,Duration,FrameCount,FrameRate,
           Frames,GraphicsList,ImageList,ImageSize,VideoEncoding}
Out[116]= rle8
Out[117]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}
During evaluation of In[115]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as video format.
During evaluation of In[115]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as video format.
Out[118]= {$Failed,$Failed}
```

It reports the same error with all avi files I tested.

Any hints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AVI is a container format. You can encode movies with totally bizar and rare formats and still call it .avi.

You could use a video format converter like [freemake](http://www.freemake.com/) to convert your movie into a format Mathematica can use. Check with `` Internal`$VideoEncodings `` what kind of internal formats are recognized.

Quite often, Quicktime (.mov) works easiest. AVIs sometimes load just fine, but don't display at all even if I have the correct codec on board and all my players can play it.

If all else fails, you can try [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/). It can read AVIs and split them into separate images, which can easily be imported into mma.

**EDIT**
I recall from my most recent video project a total failure to read the AVIs I got from having the FireFox plugin DownloadHelper download a certain YouTube movie (though it played in all the players I have, VLC, Media Player Classic, Windows Media player etc.). A conversion by DH to .mov worked but DH inserts its logo into it. So finally I resorted to a download with FreeMake and conversion to individual frames by means of VirtualDub.

Comment: The Mma help could be a little more helpful on this one :(

Comment: @belisarius codecs and their configuration are like black magic.

Comment: @Sjoerd $VideoEncodings aborts and gives me **"QuickTime" format is supported only if "QuickTime Player is installed"** I do not want to install QT ...

Comment: @belisarius QT is not that bad, is it? Anyway, in that case you should probably resort to the route sketched in the last sentence of my last edit

Comment: @Sjoerd: If you open and close the code with two backticks, you can use a backtick inside it. I've edited your post. Pl see if that's what you intended.

Comment: @Sjoerd http://temp.tinytall.de/ Comes from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601570/optimizing-algorithm-for-segmentation-through-image-substraction ... in case you want to give it a try

Comment: @belisarius I played with the movie and it seems the best way to go is to use VirtualDub and convert the movie to MJPEG. Mathematica can read that (at least, my installation can). I'll temporarily store the converted video at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3675222/tracking_video_001mjpeg.avi. None of the MPEG4 endodings worked for me. Mathematica reads them but I end up with white frames.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It doesn't look that way. The internal codings as shown with the above command, vary from the codecs installed by the k-lite package I use. I feel movie support is lacking in mma.

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks a lot. I already did that after your recommendation yesterday!

Comment: @Mr. I don't think so. Mma was unable to identify the movie until I installed QT

Comment: Weird. I have a lot of codecs, often using them to make game videos in VirtualDub, but Mathematica says: In[1]:= Internal`$VideoEncodings

Out[1]= {"Uncompressed"}`. Windows 7, Mathematica 8.

Comment: @Nakilon I get this response: {"Animation", "BMP", "Cinepak", "Component Video", "DVCPRO - PAL", 
"DV/DVCPRO - NTSC", "DV - PAL", "Graphics", "H.261", "H.263", "JPEG 
2000", "Motion JPEG A", "Motion JPEG B", "MPEG-4 Video", "Photo - 
JPEG", "Planar RGB", "PNG", "Sorenson Video", "TGA", "TIFF", 
"Uncompressed", "Video"}, but still  most (perhaps all) avi's fail to load.